# Speed up table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I,ve created a function that creates a random address, but it is taking far too long for each call (around 10 - 20 seconds). I have to run this on over 900,000 records, and by my calculations on the timing of this function, that would take 120 days give or take. Here is the function:

```
CREATE function dbo.fn_GetAddress2 (@state NVARCHAR(20))
returns @NewAddress TABLE
(   
    Address1    NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Address2    NVARCHAR(MAX),
    City        NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Postcode    NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Address1   NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Address2   NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @City       NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Postcode   NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @StreetPID  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @newID1     NVARCHAR(36)

    SELECT @StreetPID =
         ( SELECT TOP 1 g.street_locality_pid AS StreetPID 
            FROM [GNAF].dbo.Street_Locality g
                INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Address_Detail aD ON g.street_locality_pid = aD.street_locality_pid
            WHERE g.street_name IS NOT NULL AND g.state != @state AND aD.flat_number IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY  (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID ))

    SELECT @Address1 =
         ( SELECT TOP 1 CAST(aD.flat_number AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + g.Street_name + ' ' + g.street_type_code AS Address1 
            FROM [GNAF].dbo.Street_Locality g
                INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Address_Detail aD ON g.street_locality_pid = aD.street_locality_pid
            WHERE g.street_name IS NOT NULL AND g.state != @state AND aD.flat_number IS NOT NULL
                    AND g.street_locality_pid = @StreetPID
            ORDER BY  (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID ))


    SELECT @postcode =
         ( SELECT TOP 1 aD.postcode AS postcode 
            FROM [GNAF].dbo.Street_Locality g
                INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Address_Detail aD ON g.street_locality_pid = aD.street_locality_pid
            WHERE g.street_name IS NOT NULL AND g.state != @state AND aD.flat_number IS NOT NULL
                    AND g.street_locality_pid = @StreetPID
            ORDER BY  (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID ))

    SELECT @City =
         ( SELECT TOP 1 l.locality_name AS city 
            FROM [GNAF].dbo.Street_Locality g
                INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Address_Detail aD ON g.street_locality_pid = aD.street_locality_pid
                INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Locality l ON aD.locality_pid = l.locality_pid
            WHERE g.street_name IS NOT NULL AND g.state != @state AND aD.flat_number IS NOT NULL
                    AND g.street_locality_pid = @StreetPID
            ORDER BY  (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID ))

    IF @Address1 IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @NewAddress
        SELECT @Address1, @Address2, @city, @postcode;
    END;
    Return;
END
GO
```

The [GNAF] database is a huge database, filled with every single address in Australia. Functions and newid() are completely new to me.

Ive tried a few different methods including CTE:

```
SET @State = 'NSW'
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(aD.flat_number AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + g.Street_name + ' ' + g.street_type_code AS Address1 
            , aD.postcode AS postcode
    FROM [GNAF].dbo.Street_Locality g
        INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Address_Detail aD ON g.street_locality_pid = aD.street_locality_pid
    WHERE g.street_name IS NOT NULL AND g.state != @state AND aD.flat_number IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID )
)
SELECT  @Address1 = ( SELECT Address1 FROM CTE )
        ,@postcode = ( SELECT postcode FROM CTE )
SELECT @Address1
        , @postcode
```

This was actually slower. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: A couple things: A better execution plan might be produced if you `CROSS JOIN` the `getNewID` table and order by the `new_id` column instead of how you're currently doing it. And assuming I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, you do not need all of those variables or a CTE or the table variable - you can do everything you want with a single select statement. e.g. `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.blah(@state NVARCHAR(20)) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(SELECT TOP 1 <all my columns> FROM <my tables and joins> CROSS JOIN getNewID AS n WHERE <conditions> ORDER BY n.new_id);`

Comment: Thanks, what ive noticed is that the query takes exactly the same time whether it returns 1 or 1000000 records, what i am trying to do now is create a dynamic SQL query to count the amount of unique state's then ill just join it together using row_number with the actual data. Just struggling to pass a variable into the CTE query as dynamic SQL

Comment: aaaand i just remembered you can use TOP (@variable) in SQL 2005 +

Comment: There is a finite (and small) number of states in Australia, it doesn't need a complex query to summarize down to that list.

Comment: why do you need a function? why do this one row at a time? are you trying to build some test data? what is the objective?

Comment: The objective is to anonymise a database for test purposes, one of the functions of the system is searching addresses on google maps, hence the need for real addresses. As for the number of states in Aus, yes there are only a few, however, since the person records are already in the database they need to match the spoofed phone number as well which already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should work for you. Please note: Rather than makin trips back and forth to a full blown address table, I simply created 5 new tables, one for each address section and populated them with data from an address table. I used 2000 for all but the state table. You can use more or less just make sure you change the modulo values in the function to match the number of rows you but in each table.

In any case, it's fast... I'll post the SET STATISTICS IO,TIME numbers based on 10,000 , 100,000 & 1,000,000 rows being generated.

```
USE tempdb;
GO 
-- Populate a series of individual tables one for each part of the address...
CREATE TABLE dbo.a1 (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Address1 VARCHAR(60) );
INSERT dbo.a1 (Address1)
SELECT TOP 2000 b.PhysAddr1 FROM Xyz.dbo.ContactBranch b WHERE b.PhysAddr1 LIKE '[0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ]%';

CREATE TABLE dbo.a2 (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Address2 VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT dbo.a2 (Address2)
SELECT TOP 2000 ISNULL(b.PhysAddr2, '') FROM Xyz.dbo.ContactBranch b;

CREATE TABLE dbo.cty (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, City VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT dbo.cty (City)
SELECT TOP 2000 b.PhysCity FROM Xyz.dbo.ContactBranch b WHERE b.PhysCity LIKE '[0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ]%';

CREATE TABLE dbo.st (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, State CHAR(2));
INSERT dbo.st (State)
SELECT s.Description FROM Xyz.dbo.LK_States s WHERE s.Description LIKE '[a-Z][a-Z]';

CREATE TABLE dbo.zip (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Zip VARCHAR(5) );
INSERT dbo.zip (Zip)
SELECT TOP 2000 LEFT(b.PhysZip10, 5) FROM Xyz.dbo.ContactBranch b WHERE b.PhysZip10 LIKE '[0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ][0-Z ]%';

/*  DROP TABLE dbo.a1; DROP TABLE dbo.a2; DROP TABLE dbo.cty; DROP TABLE dbo.st; DROP TABLE dbo.zip; */
/*
(2000 rows affected)
(2000 rows affected)
(2000 rows affected)
(52 rows affected)
(2000 rows affected)
*/
```

The function code...

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO 
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_AddressGenerator
/* ===================================================================
10/06/2017 JL, Created: to randomly generate random addresses.
    The general premmise is based on the Ben-Gan" or inline Tally table.
=================================================================== */
--===== Define I/O parameters
(
    @State CHAR(2),
    @NumToCreate INT 
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   --rows
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100 rows
        cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),                             -- 10,000 rows
        cte_Tally (n) AS (
            SELECT TOP (@NumToCreate)
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
            FROM
                cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b                                                    -- 100,000,000 rows
            )
    SELECT 
        a1.Address1,
        a2.Address2,
        c.City,
        State = IIF(s1.State = @State, s2.State, s1.State),
        z.Zip
    FROM
        cte_Tally t
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
            ABS(CHECKSUM(t.n)) % 2000 + 1, ABS(CHECKSUM(t.n)) % 1528 + 1,
            ABS(CHECKSUM(t.n)) % 2000 + 1, ABS(CHECKSUM(t.n)) % 52 + 1,
            ABS(CHECKSUM(t.n)) % 52 + 1,   ABS(CHECKSUM(t.n)) % 2000 + 1 
            ) ) x (Add1, Add2, City, State1, State2, Zip)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.a1.Address1 FROM dbo.a1    WHERE x.Add1 = dbo.a1.ID) a1
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.a2.Address2 FROM dbo.a2    WHERE x.Add2 = dbo.a2.ID) a2
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.cty.City    FROM dbo.cty   WHERE x.City = dbo.cty.ID) c
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.st.State  FROM dbo.st    WHERE x.State1 = dbo.st.ID) s1
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.st.State  FROM dbo.st    WHERE x.State2 = dbo.st.ID) s2
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Zip.Zip     FROM dbo.zip   WHERE x.Zip = dbo.zip.ID) z;
GO
```

The actual execution of the function...

```
SELECT ag.Address1, ag.Address2, ag.City,ag.State, ag.Zip
FROM dbo.tfn_AddressGenerator('FL',10000) ag;
```

Sample output...

```
Address1                    Address2    City             State Zip
--------------------------- ----------- ---------------- ----- -----
111 CONGRESSIONAL BLVD                  ATLANTA          AL    30042
414 Eagle Rock Ave # 100    STE 400     MARIETTA         AR    70816
414 Eagle Rock Ave Ste 107  Suite 300   NORCROSS         AZ    72116
3931 HIGHWAY 78 W STE B200              SAVANNAH         CA    31702
4728 Joseph Eli Dr          STE 6       STONE MOUNTAIN   CO    30338
29620 IH10 West                         DULUTH           CT    63026
4666 El Camino Real                     ATLANTA          DC    60555
3700 Thomas Rd Ste 215      STE 100     ATLANTA          DE    32241
3700 Thomas Rd Ste 215      STE B-2190  ALPHARETTA       FL    36117
2615 East West Connector                ALPHARETTA       GA    35201
```

**10,000 row results...**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(10000 rows affected)
Table 'zip'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'st'. Scan count 0, logical reads 40000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'cty'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'a2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'a1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 94 ms,  elapsed time = 93 ms.
```

**100,000 row results...**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(100000 rows affected)
Table 'zip'. Scan count 0, logical reads 200000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'st'. Scan count 0, logical reads 400000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'cty'. Scan count 0, logical reads 200000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'a2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 200000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'a1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 200000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 907 ms,  elapsed time = 948 ms.
```

**1,000,000 row results...**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 31 ms, elapsed time = 51 ms.

(1000000 rows affected)
Table 'a1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'a2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3056, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'cty'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'st'. Scan count 0, logical reads 208, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'zip'. Scan count 0, logical reads 4000, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 10921 ms,  elapsed time = 15743 ms.
```

100K rows in less than a second & 1 million rows in ~15 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

Figured the easiest way was to just run it against each state with an amount variable, here is the code:

```
 DECLARE @states TABLE (name NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @states (name)
SELECT DISTINCT
    State
FROM anon_AddressChange


DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @i  INT
SET @i = 0
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @states)

while @i < @count 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @state NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @State = ( SELECT top 1 name from @states order by name )

    DECLARE @amount INT
    SET @amount = ( SELECT count(*) FROM anon_addresschange where state = @state )





    ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT TOP (@amount) CAST(aD.flat_number AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + g.Street_name + ' ' + g.street_type_code AS Address1 
                , aD.postcode AS postcode
                , l.locality_name AS city 

        FROM [GNAF].dbo.Street_Locality g
            INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Address_Detail aD ON g.street_locality_pid = aD.street_locality_pid
            INNER JOIN [GNAF].dbo.Locality l ON aD.locality_pid = l.locality_pid
        WHERE g.street_name IS NOT NULL AND g.state = @state AND aD.flat_number IS NOT NULL
            AND g.state NOT IN ('OT', 'NT' ,'TAS' ,'VIC' ,'ACT')
        ORDER BY  (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID )
    )
    UPDATE anon_addresschange SET
        newStreet1      = UPPER(LEFT(a.Address1,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(a.Address1,2,LEN(a.Address1)))
        ,newCity        = UPPER(LEFT(a.city,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(a.city,2,LEN(a.city)))
        ,newPostcode    = a.postcode
        ,newState       = @state
        ,newCountry     = 'Australia'
    FROM (
    SELECT  *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(GETDATE() AS TIMESTAMP)) AS RowNumber from cte ) a
    CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(GETDATE() AS TIMESTAMP)) AS RowNumber FROM anon_AddressChange
     WHERE state = @state) b
     WHERE a.Rownumber = b.Rownumber
        AND anon_addresschange.personID = b.personID


     SET @i = @i + 1
     delete from @states WHERE NAME IN ( SELECT TOP 1 name FROM @states order by name )
END
```

All I really have to do is use this in an update/insert statement.

This took 2 seconds to run for 1003 records, so 33 minutes for the 1,000,000 records.